# Is Percival related to someone?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the 4 knights of the apocalypse, Lancelot looks like the newer version of his father Ban (and perhaps also of his uncle King), Gawain is like the newer version of Merlin and Escanor (she has their powers), Tristan is like the newer version of Meliodas and Elizabeth (he has their powers) and there is Percival. Is his supposed to be like the newer version of someone or a complete original new character?